# What is a "wait thread"?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, threadpool

The documentation for the [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061.aspx) function mentions a "wait thread", but I cannot find any explanation/reference on what that is exactly.

I presume it is not a regular thread, as otherwise `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` would block a thread only waiting and doing nothing.

Comment: this is usual thread from thread pool. but it can wait on multiple objects, apc, timer signals, io completion etc. all this threads only waiting on work (object signaled, apc,etc) and call user callbacks

Comment: are those the same as completion I/O port threads in the CLR then?

Comment: all this is worked threads from pool. the implementation depend from windows version. in win2000/xp for i/o port exist separate threads which wait only on IOCP via `ZwRemoveIoCompletion`. apc/timer thread wait via `ZwDelayExecution`. wait threads which wait via `ZwWaitForMultipleObjects`. begin from vista thread pool serious redisigned. exist new api `ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkingFactory` which let not break threads for timer,i/o, wait. exist new pool api (`CreateThreadpool` etc) but all this is threads only

Comment: `ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory` correct api name

Comment: Someone mentioned in another q&a that a wait thread, although it is a regular thread, can wait on multiple handles (63) so at least it's not one thread per signal. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a waitable object handle to `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`, along with a timeout and a callback. It obtains a thread from an internal thread pool, and that thread waits on the object to be signaled or the timeout to elapse, and then it calls the callback.  So, a "wait thread" is simply a thread that waits on something to happen.

Comment: Indeed, looks like you're right, although someone mentioned that it can wait on multiple signals (up to 63) making it at least a bit more efficient.